# How can I install YouCompleteMe vim plugin on raspbian

Tags: raspbian, software-compilation

You complete me requires vim version 7.3.584+ ,mine version is:

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.3 (2010 Aug 15, compiled Feb 20 2013 06:48:10) Included patches: 1-547
```

Can I still install it somehow? I suppose compiling vim from source would be horrible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK,

Run the following commands in order in the terminal:

`sudo apt-get build-dep vim-gnome`
This command gets all the build dependencies you need.

`sudo apt-get install mercurial`
This gives you Mercurial version control system needed to download the latest Vim source code.

`hg clone https://vim.googlecode.com/hg/ vim`
This downloads the Vim source code to the subdirectory vim of the current directory.

`cd vim/src`
This changes to the right directory.

Now let's configure Vim for compilation (with "huge" features - see [Vim Features Table](http://www.drchip.org/astronaut/vim/vimfeat.html) for a description of the different feature sets)

`./configure --prefix=/usr/local --with-features=huge`
If `./configure` finished without any problems, then run:

`make && sudo make install`
And you should have the latest version of vim.

Comment: I see vim-gnome, so I suppose this is for graphical vim. I am not using graphical environment.

Comment: Please provide the substance of the answer, not only a link.  The link may be moved or removed at any time which would render this answer useless.

Comment: Note that the code is not on googlecode.com anymore, see: http://www.vim.org/sources.php. You can now use git: `git clone https://github.com/vim/vim.git`.